# Any idea why reCAPTCHA won't hide?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I've used the code as advised by Google to hide the reCAPTCHA but it is still showing (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq).  I've added it as CSS into my theme (Divi) on Wordpress but it's not working.  Any idea's why it won't hide?
Thanks,
Emma

Comment: You have to enable device check api in Google cloud console.

Comment: Not sure how that would affect the visibility of the reCAPTCHA on my website?

Comment: yes you are right, it works only if are using SafetyNet in google console, If you do not know what is safetyNet (means you are not using that), then please ignore my answer thanks. Good luck